# Out of memory error when loading a text file in to List even though I have specified large enough xmx

Tags: java, list, collections, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am getting out of memory error when I try to load a 39MB text in a List with -Xms32m -Xmx128m. so I started to increase the Xmx little by little until its loaded successfully and found out I need at least Xmx170m to load the 39MB file in the memory

I am wondering, why do I need such a large amount of memory?  I try to calculate the amount of memory being allocated in the list using UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 but none of them seem to match the Xmx at the point where is get the out of memory exception. So what is the correct way to calculate the allocated memory?

Can someone please explain what am I missing here?

Below is the output and code sample with at -Xms32m -Xmx128m

```
Max memory 129 MB.
Total memory 32 MB.
Free memory 32 MB.
Input file size 39 MB.
Out Of Memory Error
List size in UFT-8 29 MB.
List size in UFT-16 58 MB.
List size in UFT-32 116 MB.
Free memory 4 MB.
End 

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.nrx.util.SortUtil.main(SortUtil.java:288)



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Max memory "+Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1000 /1000+" MB.");
    System.out.println("Total memory "+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1000 /1000+" MB.");
    System.out.println("Free memory "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1000 /1000+" MB.");

    long utf8 = 0;
    long utf16 = 0;
    long utf32 = 0;
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try 
    {
        File inFile = new File("data/input38.log");
        System.out.println("Input file size "+inFile.length()/1000 /1000+" MB.");
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
        String line = fileReader.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            utf8 = utf8 + line.getBytes("UTF-8").length;
            utf16 = utf16 + line.getBytes("UTF-16").length;
            utf32 = utf32 + line.getBytes("UTF-32").length;

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                strList.add(st.nextToken().trim());
            line = fileReader.readLine();
        }

    } 
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Out Of Memory Error ");
        System.out.println("List size in UFT-8 "+utf8/1000 /1000+" MB.");
        System.out.println("List size in UFT-16 "+utf16/1000 /1000+" MB.");
        System.out.println("List size in UFT-32 "+utf32/1000 /1000+" MB.");
        System.out.println("Free memory "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1000 /1000+" MB.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("End ");
}
```

Comment: `-Xmx128m`  (tilts head)  You do realize the ***default*** memory of a Java app. running in a 1.6 JRE is around 256 meg, right?

Comment: Good point, Andrew. I even did not pay attention on this fact.

Comment: @AlexR Didn't it ***used to be*** around 64 meg?  Without me noticing, it seems to have migrated upwards over the years.

Comment: yes i understand that, i am trying different memory settings and file size finf the co-relation between file size and memory setting. The 39MB file loads fine with xmx256, but i get the same error when i try a larger file, say 100MB

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is because you are using `ArrayList`. ArrayList is at smart wrapper over simple array. When list is growing up ArrayList creates new array and copies the old content to the new one. First, it is extremely not efficient. Second, it requires at list triple size each time: n elements in old array and n*2 elements in the new one.

So, try to use `LinkedList` instead. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: with LinkedList i get 

Max memory 129 MB.
Total memory 32 MB.
Free memory 32 MB.
Input file size 39 MB.
Out Of Memory Error 
List size in UFT-8 22 MB.
List size in UFT-16 44 MB.
List size in UFT-32 89 MB.
Free memory 111 MB.
End 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringCoding.safeTrim(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringCoding.access$300(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

You're using ArrayList. So it is a list based on array. There is no way to change size of array without create new, bigger one. New array need to be allocated and all elements need to be copied to the bigger one (with some empty space to make adding some amount of elements not so heavy). Try to use String[] table with specified amount of elements to minimize size of it in memory and avoid array copy.

And I'm not sure but I think that in Java, characters in strings are always 16-bit?

And Strings in Java are shared and optimized, so calculation of size of String are not trivial operation.

Edit:
I see that someone mention about LinkedList, be aware that in that list there are always additional pointer variables that also need to be stored in memory.

Comment: it is not possible to know the size unless I look through the file first to count the words before create the array list. Is there any implementation of collection where I don’t need to set the size and be memory efficient when growing large?

Comment: no but it is not hard to implement it by yourself , key part is when capacity is changed, try for example increase capacity only by small number and create MyList<String[]> - every time add new array of capacity 1000 for example - you will only work on references so no array copy will be performed

Comment: If memory is bottle neck, then maybe try to parse file once to get information about how much memory you should allocate and then parse it again and load words.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others at some point even if the file size is small you may need extra memory for copying the array list around.

For better picture you can try to find how much extra memory is required for say every 10 MB increase in file size. Some amount of memory is going to be constant and is needed irrespective of file size.

Secondly you should also measure the memory after doing full GC. you can see where memory is being taken up using JVisualVm.

Answer (score 0):

Default capacity of ArrayList is 10, after that its capacity is doubled, so if you have 100 000 elements the real allocated capacity can be 200 000, that could be the reason for this exception